# How to change the Admin port on Glassfish inside a script

Tags: glassfish

Got a weird Glassfish issue here. Here's how to reproduce it:

(1) Install Glassfish v3
(2) Start your default domain:

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

(3) Change the admin port (you'll need to enter admin uid & password, in our script we use the -u & -W parameters):

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.admin-listener.port=34848
```

(4) Shut down the domain:

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin stop-domain domain1
```

You'll see this doesn't work. You get:

```
CLI306 Warning - server is not running.
Command stop-domain executed successfully.
```

But your Glassfish process is still running. Worse, when you attempt to start the process you'll get a warning that some of your ports are already in use. Of course they are, the old process has still got 'em! Your only way out is `killall -9 java`

While some of the config changes are dynamic it seems this one isn't but the domain stop assumes it **is** dynamic and uses the new port to try and execute the command.

Possible solutions are:

(1) Use `sed` on `domain.xml` - would prefer not to as it's complicated & risky grepping through XML code. I've seen Glassfish change the order of attributes in this file so we can't just sed for `port="4848"`
(2) Use the scripted installer rather than the zip file and feed the parameters to the setup program as an answer file - this is problematic for our install scripts which are required to be idem potent.
(3) Use a custom crafted zip of the Glassfish install archive with domain.xml already changed - not an option as the port we are setting may change in the future.

This is almost the definition of a corner case but one we need to solve. For now we're going to sed domain.xml but it would be nice to know if there was a way that's possible via the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do the following instead...

1. install v3 by unzipping
2. delete domain1
3. create a new domain1 using the ports that you prefer.
   The [man page for the create-domain subcommand](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1758/create-domain-1?l=en&a=view) will have all the details
4. start this new domain...

No extra start or stop necessary  (and you can skip step 2 if you are willing to remember to say 'asadmin start-domain mydomain' instead of 'asadmin start-domain'

Answer (score 0):

Sed wasn't as bad as I thought it might be, here's what I did:

```
cd $GLASSFISH_HOME
sed -i.bak '/<network-listener[^>]*name="admin-listener"/s/port="4848"/port="34848"/g' glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml
```

It's still a bug that asadmin thinks the port change is dynamic when it isn't but I can live with this hack.